# Как корректно убрать возможность скрола вложенных RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть горизонтальный `RecyclerView` c элементами содержащие вертикальные `RecyclerView`. При пролистывании горизонтального (назовем его родительским) `RecyclerView` есть возможность прекратив свайп (родительский содержит `PagerSnapHelper` для "долистывания") пролистать дочерний `RecyclerView`, что за собой приведет к остановке свайпа родительского.

Каким образом можно корректно отключать при дочерние элементы?

В голову приходит не очень корректное решение прокидывать событие на начало/завершение скрола в дочерние элементы которые бы просто отключали/дизейблели всю `View` (которая содержит в том числе дочерние `RecyclerView`)

Comment: переопределить у layoutManager метод canScrollVerticaly и в нем можно запретить скролл